# Tomcat web app debug database connection

Tags: java, linux, debugging, web-applications, datasource

I have java web app running in tomcat in Linux environment

I want to debug db connection URL of existing running web application application.

Some time ago one of colleague showed me the Linux command to trace out applications external links. Unfortunately I don't have that command any more.

If any one can help me ??

Comment: Oh yeah some thing like that. Can u post the pull command pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following command monitors eh0 network adapter and creates log in .pcap file

```
tcpdump -w 08232010.pcap -i eth0
```

Following command convert .pcap data into readable format.

```
read .pcap tcpdump -tttt -r 08232010.pcap
```